# Swift - get results from completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I have this method that is inside a class called WebService, inside this method I am getting data from an API:

```
func GetTableDataOfPhase(phase: String, completion: (result: AnyObject) -> Void)
    {
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let requestString = NSString(format:"%@?jobNo=%@", webservice, phase) as String
        let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: requestString)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            {
                do
                {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [AnyObject]

                    completion(result: json!)
                }
                catch
                {
                    print(error)
                }
            })

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

Now I am calling this method from another class like so:

```
WebService().GetTableDataOfPhase("ORC0005")
    {
        (result: AnyObject) in
        self.data = result as! NSArray
    }
```

This works as expected. Now I am trying to get the results from the completion handler

so I can do this:

```
WebService().GetTableDataOfPhase("ORC0005")
        {
            (result: AnyObject) in
            self.data = result as! NSArray
        }

        print(self.data.count)
```

right now self.data.count is 0, but when I put this print statement inside the curly braces, it is 70, how do I get the results outside the curly braces so I can use self.data.count ?

Comment: You should update your question showing how you are actually intending to use the data.

Comment: The completion handler is called asynchronously. So do it the other way round. Use the results **inside** the curly braces. And use consistent types, `[AnyObject]` -> `AnyObject` -> `NSArray` are three different types for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here is your problem, you're calling dataTaskWithURL(async).

At the time you do:

```
 print(self.data.count)
```

Your web service call is not finished yet.

When you put this line inside the curly braces, it only runs when the call has a response. That's why it works as expected.

It's a matter of timing, you're tying to evaluate a value that's not there yet.

Answer (score -1):

In your class add

```
var yourData:NSArray?
```

And in your method

```
 WebService().GetTableDataOfPhase("ORC0005")
            {
                (result: AnyObject) in
                for res in result 
              {
                   self.yourData.append(res)
               }


            }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    print(self.yourData.count)


    }
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything, it's a timing issue.

Comment: That still wouldn't fix anything

Comment: *dispatching* the print line doesn't change anything either.